# Using the PSS, how do you ask anyone to battle?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm playing Pokemon Y and recently, while using the PSS, I saw someone with a white sign on their avatar. When I selected him, it automatically prompted me for battle. I wanna know how to do that. Does anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

In the first **PSS** menu you have this page:
[image]

If you tap **Battle** you open a new menu where you can choose what kind of battle you want: *Infrared*, *Local* and *Internet*. If you choose "Internet" and select which battle options you like, you have to choose who you want to challenge. At the bottom of the screen, there's a button that lets you invite Friends and Acquaintance. Then, the game will automatically search for a challenger.

Probably for a friend or an acquaintance this "search" will have the look of a special icon on your avatar. I can't figure out any other process.

Comment: thanks alot ,and by the way the icon was something like a shout out,it was moving,it had a battle sign on it and was white.